# Substitute string for line in command result bash

Tags: bash, email, ldap

I have a file with a list of users and ips, tab separated. I want, in this file to substitute the user name for the mail of the user I obtain with a `ldapsearch` query.

I managed to get the ldapsearch result on a nice list of users and mails, also tab separated.

What's the easiest way to do this in bash?

***Sample input***:

**File**

```
name1<tab>ip1<tab>other stuff 1
name2<tab>ip2<tab>other stuff 2
...
```

**Ldap output**

```
name1 (mail1)
name2 (mail2)
...
```

**Desired output** (Transform file)

```
mail1<tab>ip1<tab>other stuff 1
mail2<tab>ip2<tab>other stuff 2
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` :

```
$ cat file
name1   ip1 other stuff 1
name2   ip2 other stuff 2
$ cat ldapoutput 
name1 (mail1)
name2 (mail2)
$ join <(tr -d '()' < ldapoutput) file | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
mail1 ip1 other stuff 1
mail2 ip2 other stuff 2
```

The following, simpler, version would leave the name on each line:

```
$ join ldapoutput file 
name1 (mail1) ip1 other stuff 1
name2 (mail2) ip2 other stuff 2
```

Note that the input files must be sorted for `join` to work. If they are not, you can use a construct like this:

```
$ join <(sort ldapoutput) <(sort file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk one-liner:

```
awk -F '[ \t()]' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$3;next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]}1' OFS='\t' ldap file
mail1   ip1     other   stuff   1
mail2   ip2     other   stuff   2
```

Using pipe with `cat -vte`:

```
mail1^Iip1^Iother^Istuff^I1$
mail2^Iip2^Iother^Istuff^I2$
```